# Sending spacebar press to game for bhop hack

Tags: c++

I followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RiS-j_ecG0A) to make a bhop cheat for cs:s using c++. In the tutorial the cheat makes an engine call to make the player jump, and it toggles using spacebar. I tried not using that and tried to simulate a spacebar press to make the player jump, but it doesn't work. I also tried making my cheat bhop only when holding spacebar and dont know whether I should use while or if infront of (GetAsyncKeyState(SPACE_BAR)) in BunnyHop().

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "HackProcess.h"

CHackProcess fProcess;
using namespace std;

const DWORD Player_Base = 0x4C6708;   
const DWORD dw_JumpOffset = 0x350;


#define FL_ONGROUND 257
#define SPACE_BAR 0x20

#define F6_KEY 0x75

bool b_true = true;
bool b_false = false;
bool BunnyHopStatus = false;

struct MyPlayer_t
{
    DWORD ClocalPlayer;
    int m_fFlags;
    void ReadInformation()
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(fProcess.__HandleProcess, (PBYTE*)    (fProcess.__dwordClient + Player_Base), &ClocalPlayer, sizeof(DWORD), 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(fProcess.__HandleProcess, (PBYTE*)(ClocalPlayer +     dw_JumpOffset), &m_fFlags, sizeof(int), 0);
    }
}MyPlayer;

void BunnyHop()
{
    INPUT space = {0};
    space.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    space.ki.wVk = VK_SPACE;

    if(GetAsyncKeyState(SPACE_BAR))
    {
        if(MyPlayer.m_fFlags == FL_ONGROUND)
        {

            SendInput(1, &space, sizeof(INPUT)); // Send KeyDown
            space.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
            SendInput(1, &space, sizeof(INPUT)); // Send KeyUp

            cout << "player on ground" << endl; //added for debugging
        }else
        {
            cout << "player whatever" << endl; //added for debugging
        }

    }

}




int main()
{
    fProcess.RunProcess();
    cout << "Game Found! Running Bunny Hop..." << endl;

    while(!GetAsyncKeyState(F6_KEY))
    {
        MyPlayer.ReadInformation();
        BunnyHop(); 
    }



}
```

(HackProcess.h: http://pastebin.com/vVauF3dS)

Answer (score 0):

```
SendKeys.Send("{SPACE BAR}");
```

Try this.